# Trying to use multi level CI controller structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Controller structure (admin.php is my controller):

```
controllers/menu/admin/admin.php
```

When I call `http://localhost/project/index.php/menu/admin/admin` I get `404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.` error message.

I've followed [this](http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/) example but still doesn't work. I'm using CI2

Any idea why?

Note: Just in case, view and controller works fine. No problem there.

Thanks

Comment: for the record that example is for codeingiter 1.7.2 and some of the things are obsolete. As you can see here, the last version of codeigniter supports folders and sub-folders on controllers out of the box http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: More [precisely](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This example](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/190563/) solved the problem.